# Performance of database with transactional data

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning

There are lots of row modifications (several thousands of rows per minute) in our PostgreSQL database that stores transactional data. We have a problem because PostgreSQL runs vacuuming process and this very slow down our database performance. I am looking for the most efficient 
solution how to solve this problem. Could be a solution some of these points?:

- Separate these transactional data into another PostgreSQL database?
- Change PostgreSQL for MySQL for better performance?

Comment: Check your configuration and your queries, PostgreSQL can do thousands of transactions per second. And still run autovacuum. MySQL is so much worse, I'm glad we got rid of it! (not a rant, just a fact in our situation)

Comment: For an educated guess what to do, you would have to provide us with an exact table definition including all indexes, triggers, foreign key and other constraints, with the typical UPDATE statements you are running, your PostgreSQL version, basic hardware and configuration, concurrent load ... In principal, several thousand updates per minute is not a problem at all.